# I am getting an error on mvn verify site

Tags: maven-plugin

It gives me this error pointing to one of the pom files. I checked the plugin and its not null. I even updated it to the latest version. still doesn't fix it.

Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.4:site failed: Anchor name cannot be null

Comment: Can you provide any kind of code and/or paste the whole errors you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that exception surfaces in a lot of cases and is incredibly unhelpful.

There was an [issue a while back](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MPIR-313) where not having a license name defined in the pom would throw this exception.

I ran into this exception (with version 3.4) where I had a typo in my changes.xml file (`verison` instead of `version`). I was only tipped off by seeing that it failed in a `ChangesReportGenerator` class. Even then I glanced over the typo several times before seeing it.

For anyone else running into this, take the time to check for even the most random typos - it might just be the problem.

---

For reference, here's the complete error message from the log:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] example.products.parent ...................... SUCCESS [0.709s]
[INFO] Example Product .............................. FAILURE [2.199s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.162s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 02 12:53:19 CDT 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/64M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.4:site (default-site) on project example.product: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.4:site failed: Anchor name cannot be null! -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.4:site (default-site) on project example.product: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.
plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.4:site failed: Anchor name cannot be null!
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.4:site failed: Anchor name cannot be null!
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Anchor name cannot be null!
        at org.apache.maven.doxia.sink.XhtmlBaseSink.anchor(XhtmlBaseSink.java:1545)
        at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.sink.SiteRendererSink.anchor(SiteRendererSink.java:253)
        at org.apache.maven.doxia.sink.XhtmlBaseSink.anchor(XhtmlBaseSink.java:1533)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.issues.AbstractIssuesReportGenerator.sinkSectionTitle2Anchor(AbstractIssuesReportGenerator.java:181)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.changes.ChangesReportGenerator.constructRelease(ChangesReportGenerator.java:528)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.changes.ChangesReportGenerator.constructReleases(ChangesReportGenerator.java:511)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.changes.ChangesReportGenerator.doGenerateReport(ChangesReportGenerator.java:230)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.changes.ChangesMojo.executeReport(ChangesMojo.java:356)
        at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate(AbstractMavenReport.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.render.ReportDocumentRenderer.renderDocument(ReportDocumentRenderer.java:224)
        at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.renderModule(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:311)
        at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.render(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:129)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.render.SiteMojo.renderLocale(SiteMojo.java:182)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.render.SiteMojo.execute(SiteMojo.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        ... 20 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
```